# Динамический URL во flask не показывает фото с сервера

Tags: python, html, flask

Делаю сайт-фотохостинг. Столкнулся с проблемой показа нужных изображений. Из динамического url адреса получаем переменные с именем файла и папки, в которой он лежит.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
    
app = Flask(__name__)
    
    
@app.route('/din/<folder_name>/<file_name>')
def test_din(folder_name, file_name):
    file = f'static\\{folder_name}\\{file_name}'
    return render_template('image_render.html', img=file)
```

`image_render.html` выглядит так

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" />
    <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if img %}
    <img src="{{img}}">
{% else %}
    <h1>Image will be render here...</h1>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Файлы на сервере расположены в папке `static`, на скрине видна попытка перехода по url `http://127.0.0.1:8001/din/est/a.jpg`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу понять, почему `render_template` не выдает нужный html с картинкой?

Если мы в функции-декораторе просто пропишем нужный URL и в `render_template` отправляем не динамические переменные, то все работает корректно. Например так

```py
@app.route('/test')  #  это работает без динамических переменных
def mi():
    file = r'static\est\a.JPG'
    print(file)
    return render_template('image_render.html', img=file)
```

В данном случае любая картинка показывается по любому пути в папке `static`.

Причем если URL сделать динамическим, но в самом шаблоне декоратора прописать жесткий адрес, то картинка тоже не будет работать.

Проблема именно в работе `render_template` и динамического url. Хотя я сравнивал полученный в обоих случаях адрес командой print() и пути оказывались идентичными.

Comment: А `static` у вас в корне сайта лежит? Ну используйте абсолютные пути, поставьте `/` в начале: `/static/...`, у вас просто путь формируется относительный, вот он и получается относительно текущего пути, а не от корня сайта. Ещё я не понял, зачем вам бэкслэши в `URL`, используйте обычные слеши, прямые.

Comment: Спасибо тебе друг. Я добавил прямой слеш перед static и у меня все заработало. Все слеши развернул в прямые и убрал двойные. Теперь в url можно для любой картинки прописать путь. А обратный слеш получался при работе os.path.join(). Он в 2 этапа собирал путь и разделял его обратным слешем. Я даже не подумал, что слеш не правильный. Не знаю как тебя лайкнуть.

Comment: Я оформил ответ, можете его лайкнуть и отметить галочкой )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из-за того, что путь к файлу в скрипте прописан относительный `'static/...`, а не абсолютный, при обращении к `URL`, указывающему не на корень сайта, а куда-то глубже `/din/est/...`, общий путь формируется вида `/din/est/static/...`, что, конечно, неправильно.

В данном случае нужно указывать абсолютный путь от корня сайта `/static`, тогда полный путь будет правильно формироваться именно от корня сайта, а не от того пути, где лежит страница, к которой идёт обращение.

Ну и поскольку речь идёт об `URL`-ях, то экранированные обратные слеши `\\` (как в файловой системе `Windows`) тут не нужны, используйте везде обычные слеши `/`, как принято в `URL` (и в `Linux`).